# Resizing partitions through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, partition

I have a dedicated hosting that runs on Linux. I have access to the server through SSH and also directadmin. This is what I get runing **df -h** command:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       188G  168G   11G  94% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       477M   30M  422M   7% /boot
/dev/sdb1       917G   72M  871G   1% /home2
/dev/sda2        32G   48M   30G   1% /swap
```

I wonder how I can resize the partitions so that sdb1 gets smaller and sda3 gets bigger and I don't lose files. There are some other topics discussing resize partition but none on SSH and Linux.

I was asked: Why is the / is so large? Answer: because there are lots of images there. 
and for the filesystem I found this command df -T and this is the result:

```
Filesystem     Type  1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      ext4  197087532 175817088  11252296  94% /
tmpfs          tmpfs   8103088         0   8103088   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1      ext4     487652     30205    431847   7% /boot
/dev/sdb1      ext4  961301832     73364 912390428   1% /home2
/dev/sda2      ext4   32896880     49080  31170080   1% /swap
```

Comment: I edited the question, please read.

Comment: It will be difficult to change the size of `/` while running the OS. One solution could be to move the folder containing the images somewhere to `/home2` and create a softlink to that place at the original location (depends on how the images are accessed).

Comment: Thanks. They are images and are displayed by html <img tag. How would I make a link to them?

Answer (score 3):

Resizing a partition that is actually used by the running operating system is nearly impossible and *highly* inadvisable to do.  How to accomplish what you are seeking to do depends on what type of dedicated hosting arrangement that you have.

If it is a *virtual* machine, you should have been given access to the hypervisor (possibly called a "control panel" or somesuch) that allows you to, for instance, power on, shut down, or reboot the machine with its emulated power switch if needed.  These interfaces also usually give you access to a 'remote console', which is a VM's version of sitting in front of the physical keyboard connected to the actual machine.  Through this, you can boot an ISO image containing a bootable version of gparted or some other partition editor, which you could then use to resize your partitions as desired.

If it is a *physical* machine, most good hosting companies offer "KVM-over-IP", which is to say, a remote way to access the actual physical console much like a VM hypervisor's console interface.  You will probably have to ask your hosting provider to put a bootable media into a USB or optical drive to boot from if your installation doesn't already have an option to boot to `parted` on the GRUB menu.  If it's *managed* hosting, they could probably do the resize for you - that is after all the management you'd be paying for in that case.

Naturally, any time you look at messing around with partition sizes, back your data up first, because if something goes wrong, recovering from a faffed up partition resize is difficult at best.

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, I did not read your `df`output thoroughly.

It is not possible to "*resize the partitions so that sdb1 gets smaller and sda3 gets bigger*", because they are on different disks (`sda` and `sdb`). From the size of the disks I suppose `sda`is a 240 GB SSD and `sdb`is a 1000G HDD.

You will only be able to move files from `sda3` to `sdb1` and eventually mount or link `sdb`back.

**One possible solution**:

Supposed most of the data in question (your images) are located somewhere below `/home`, you could move these to what is `/home2`at the moment, and then mount `/dev/sdb1` as `/home`. As the used size supposes, there are no data on `/home2`. If there are any, you first just move them anywhere else.

**Beware:** If you are not very familiar with Linux, this could be dangerous, as moving data in use (your HOME directory) in a running system may end up not to be able to log you in again.

**Another possible (and maybe simpler) solution**:

Say, your login account is `me`and the images are in directory `/home/me/images`. You could then move them to say `/home2/me/images` by issuing

```
sudo mkdir /home2/me
sudo chown me:me /home2/me
mv -v /home/me/images /home2/me
ln -s /home2/me/images /home/me
```

In detail:

- With root rights (`sudo`) create a directory `/home/me`and change the ownership to `me`.
- Move the folder `images`to the newly created directory; `-v` tells you what is going on. This may take a long time; do not interrupt the move, as continuing after interruptions will be tricky.
- After having moved the folder (and its contents, of course), create a symbolic link to the new position in place of the old one.

Now you should be able to work with the images folder as you did before. Sometimes you may have to change some configurations, as not all software allows to follow symbolic links for security reasons (e.g. apache when using `public_html`folder or samba when links point to folders outside the shared folder).

If you could give more information (`/path/to/images`, what is on `/home2`, how are the files accessed by the httpd, what is the content of `/etc/fstab`) I could advise more detailed.

**And don't forget to always have a current and reliable backup of your valuable data!**